# uncheck all textboxes when user select a certain checbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my code. What I want is that when I choose a checkbox the other checkbox will uncheck... same behavior like radio button.. but using td class... is it possible in jquery?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="example">
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td class="example">
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td class="example">
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td class="example">
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: show jquery/javascript code you have tried ??

Comment: Why are you not using a radio input for this?

Comment: CMS and mockup design problem... the mockup design looks like this got no choice... and the cms that I'm using is a bit difficult when it comes to radio buttons..

Comment: @ user3113490 you `radio button` if you want radio button like behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('table').on('click', ':checkbox', function() {
// On click of any checkbox inside the table

    // If checkbox is checked then only uncheck others
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('table').find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/yz5yjwwu/

Comment: this line is not necessary `if ($(this).is(':checked')) {`

Comment: Optimization, when clicked on same checkbox

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('.example').click(function() {
   $('.example').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
   $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w7977s9r/)

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the trouble guys... I already got it..

here's the code...

```
$('.example input').on('click', function() {
   $('.example input').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
```

Comment: You need to check if the checkbox is checked or not, http://stackoverflow.com/a/30476090/2025923

Answer (score 1):

that's it :)

```js
         $("input[type='checkbox']").on("change",function(){
              $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",false);
              $(this).prop("checked",true);
         });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="example">
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td class="example">
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td class="example">
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td class="example">
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code   . working  [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dagegegawu/4/)

```
$(":checkbox").on('click',function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $('td.example :checkbox').prop("checked",false);
      $(this).prop("checked",true);
    }
});
```